# Java UI app framework for mobile device

Tags: java, swing, mobile, desktop-application

I develop and use a Java Swing Application framework (see [pGAF](http://www.plealog.com)), mostly until now for quickly creating standalone desktop applications for Linux, MacOS and Windows.

Now, I'm wondering whether or not such a desktop framework could be used on a mobile device running Java?

I'm a newbie on mobile device development, and as far as possible, I'd like to "transfer" my work for reuse on such devices.

Do you have any hints for me to start with?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering whether or not such a desktop framework could be used on a mobile device running Java?

No.  A Java based mobile device would be running either Android Java or J2ME.  Both of those languages have a GUI toolkit that is appropriate for the device, and neither supports Swing.